# How can I create equally distributed columns and rows in README (GitHub)

Tags: github, markdown, github-actions, github-flavored-markdown, readme

My current table looks like the following: [Current Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTp6s.png)

How can I change the markdown so that the text column spans from the edge of the smaller images? Moreover, how can I make all the rows in columns 2 and 3 of equal height?

Comment: easy way https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables

Answer (score 0):

To quote the documentation for [Attribute Lists](https://python-markdown.github.io/extensions/attr_list/), one of built-in markdown extensions:

> If the tables extension is enabled, attribute lists can be defined on table cells. To differentiate attributes for an inline element from attributes for the containing cell, the attribute list must be separated from the content by at least one space and be defined at the end of the cell content. As table cells can only ever be on a single line, the attribute list must remain on the same line as the content of the cell.

So, since I'm pretty sure the Tables extension is enabled on GH ;) you can do something like this to test the Attributes Lists (taken from the same docs and tweaked):

```markdown
| set on td    | set on em   |
|--------------|-------------|
| *a* { width="50%" } | *b*{ width="100%" } { width="50%" } |
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This doesn't do anything using the GitHub Wiki markdown. It creates, a table, but the { width="50%" } texts are displayed as, well, texts. Do you have any suggestions on how I should proceed?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer... Unluckily, I'm wondering if it's possible at all since it looks like they didn't activate the mentioned extension. I'll try to find out more details.